# Tenho uma lib em React, usando Rollup e instalei @material-ui/icons , erro ao buildar... já importei no rollup mesmo assim não resolveu

Tags: react, typescript, styled-components

Erro que ocorre ao buildar
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicionei no rollup.config as dep do material icons e core... mesmo assim o erro continuou o mesmo. alguem poderia ajudar? por favor. uma sugestão..
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]